# What is the cut point where "quick sort" transforms from nlgn to n2?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I know the worst case of the algorithm - which is when the elements are already sorted or when all the elements are same,but want to know the point at which the algorithm moves from a complexity of nlgn to n2.

Comment: well, when the elements are already sorted.

Comment: ... and the choice of pivot you select is always the 1st (or the last element).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how we choose the **pivot**.

One view says that when all the elements are already sorted. Well, it is not 100% right. In this condition, if we choose the first element as the pivot, the complexity becomes **N^2**.

Since we have,

`T(N) = T(N-1) + cN (N >1)`, if you are good at basic math, then:

```
 T(N) = O(N^2)
```

As mentioned above, it depends on **how we choose the pivot**. Although in some textbooks, it chooses the first pivot mainly, that is not recommenced.

One popular method is : **median-of-three partitioning**. It choose median value of a[left],a[right] and a[(left+right)/2].

Comment: Is there a specific "point" at which this transition takes place?

Answer (score 0):

The worst case time for quick sort occurs when the chosen pivot does not divide the array. For example, if we choose the first element as the pivot every time and the array is already sorted, then the array is not divided at all. Hence the complexity is O(n^2).

To avoid this we randomize the index for the pivot. Assuming that the pivot splits the array in two equal sized parts we have a complexity of O(n log n).

For exact analysis see Formal analysis section in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0):

It will perform worst i.e,

O(n^2)

in following cases

1. If the list is already sorted and pivot is first element
2. If list is sorted in reverse order and pivot is last element.
3. If all elements are same in the list. In this case pivot selection do not matter.

Note- Already sorted cannot be the worst case if pivot is selected as median.